# How the android application knows when the heads up notification disappears?

Tags: android, android-notifications, heads-up-notifications

We need to display the heads up notification when our application receives a notification and application is running in foreground. If application receives any other notifications while the current notification is in display, we need to queue the notifications, pop it from the queue and display it when the current notification disappears. Since the heads up notification automatically disappears from screen (remains visible in the notification drawer), I am not sure how our application knows when the heads up notification disappears from screen. Is there any event our application receives? Can any one please let me know if there is any mechanism to know when the heads up notification disappears?

Comment: local broadcast receiver maybe help you.

Comment: @MohammadDavari: Understood broadcast receiver. But not sure what action I need to pass as a parameter to the AddAction() of IntentFilter to receive notification updates.

Comment: you can register localboadcastreceiver and when you want say this notification is going to be disappear sendbroadcast and when receive the broadcastreceiver, onreceive method override will be call.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand that. "when you want say this notification is going to be disappear sendbroadcast" - How do I know when the notification is going to disappear, to send broadcast.

Comment: I modified the question to give more clarity. The heads-up notification appears the moment your app issues the notification and it disappears from screen after a moment, but remains visible in the notification drawer as usual. So application doesn't do any thing to make the notification disappear from screen. It will be done by OS. So how my app knows when the heads up notification is going to disappear from screen? Does the OS send any event or any message when it is taking down the heads up notification from screen?